# Python, the Console and exporting to a file

Tags: python, function, docx

I have a function that prints text to the console.  Below is a version of what the code looks like (it's actually a lot of lines of a story, so I'm summarizing it.)  My question is - is there another function I can write to take all_text() and generate a docx file with the it? I've managed to create a .txt file, but I would ideally like to create something with formatting options.

```py
from docx import Document


document = Document()

def all_text():
     print("Line1\nLine2\nLine3")

document.add_paragraph(all_text())
document.save("demo.docx")
```

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I am familiar with this doc, the problem I have is that my function is no longer regarded as a string, so I couldn't get this to work.  If I can get around that issue, then the above link is exactly what I would like to use.

Comment: Why isn't your function regarded as a string anymore?

Comment: @Jamie
I've just updated the question with the fuller code.  It generates an empty tile, I'm assuming because the function is not a string.

Comment: Your function prints a string but doesn't look like it returns anything. `document.add_paragraph(...)` will expect an input. If your function doesn't `return` anything - then nothing will be added. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7129293/4590710). Hopefully it makes it clear that the function needs to pass back a value to the _caller_.

Comment: _my function is no longer regarded as a string_ ..... _because the function is not a string_ It's a function, it will never be a string.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's simply a matter of understanding functions and returning values, there have been plenty like it, and I can't see it being of any use in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Document.add_paragraph()` expects a string. Your `all_text()` function is not returning a string, but writing to `sys.stdout` (which is by default redirected to your console) and (implicitely) returning `None`.

The clean solution is of course to change your `all_text()` function so that it returns a string instead of writing to `sys.stdout` ie

```
def all_text():
    return "Line1\nLine2\nLine3"
```

If your real function actually does a lot of printing in different places and/or call functions which themselves print to stdout etc, making the "clean solution" impractical or too expensive, you can also hack around by redirecting `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` and sending the collected values to `add_paragraph`, ie:

```
import sys
try:
   from io import StringIO # py3
except ImportError:
   from cStringIO import StringIO

def all_text():
     print("Line1\nLine2\nLine3")


def get_all_text():
    sys.stdout = buffer = StringIO
    try:
        all_text()
        return  buffer.getvalue()
    finally:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

document.add_paragraph(get_all_text())
```

Comment: Thank you .  I am interested in the clean function, so I appreciate the suggestion.  It gets me more where I need to be.  I couldn't simply do return "Line123", I had to set a variable to equal the string, and then return the variable.